# How to view tables used in hbase database?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am new to hbase. There are 30 tables created in `hbase`. I want to view those table structures.

I have used the below command to view the tables but there is only one table. Hope I need to connect to right database inside `hbase` to list the tables.

```
hbase(main):017:0> list
TABLE
test
1 row(s) in 0.0140 seconds
```

Now I wanted the command to know what are the databases present(already created) in `hbase`?

Answer (score 4):

To be align with HBase terminology... There is a concept of 'namespace'.
You can create tables under particular namespaces.

```
Group name: namespace
  Commands: alter_namespace, create_namespace, describe_namespace, drop_namespace, list_namespace, list_namespace_tables
```

`list` - display tables in default namespace

`list_namespace` - shows all available namespace

`list_namespace_tables 'n1'` shows all tables under `n1` namespace.

Most likely all your tables were created under some specific namespace. Explore..

Answer (score 1):

There is a way you can do it with [HAdmin](https://hadmin.io/?utm_source=so&utm_campaign=viewTables). Click to the "Tables" link on the sidebar and you will see all your tables. 
[image: HAdmin full view]